# Problem inserting into an SQL Server Database with Java

Tags: java, sql-server, insert

I have a problem because I can't insert into an sql server database:

driver:[Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]

```
public int sendCabecera(String tpv, Date date, String time, int NumPers, int CodOfi) {

    java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dm = null;
    int result = 0;

    try {
        connection = this.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            dm = connection.getMetaData();

            Statement select = connection.createStatement();


            String sql="INSERT INTO TCabecerasSolicitudes(CodigoTPV, FechaYHora, Hora, NumeroPersonas, CodigoOficina) VALUES ('001','17/08/2011 16:00','De 16 a 17',0, '001');";

            select.execute(sql);


//{.... catch ... etc }
```

Well I have tried all execute update and execute alone and I always het the same error: 
"Cannot insert NULL" this is the first comlumn which is a primary key and normally auto-increment so I just ignore it but it doesn't work why???

Thanks a lot in advance,

**EDIT: problem solved I turned out the key in question was not autoincrement**

Comment: Post the full table definition please.

Comment: Are you sure that the SQL works if you execute it manually?  JDBC should be broadly equivalent to just executing the same statement in a Sql Server Management Studio window...

Comment: configure your column for your primary key with autoincrement and a start value. A good example for a start value is Zero. Or you let the cms create for it own, using the UUID format.

Comment: sorry guys the mistake was from the database, it is solved now thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems most likely that you have a column in your `TCabecerasSolicitudes` table that is defined as `NOT NULL` but which is not listed in your insert statement (ie not one of `CodigoTPV, FechaYHora, Hora, NumeroPersonas, CodigoOficina`).

Because you have not provided a value for that column in your query and it's `NOT NULL`, the statement is exploding.